# Corosync 2.3.3: Unable to enable cipher

Tags: high-availability, heartbeat, pacemaker, corosync, crm

I'm trying to set up a new pacemaker/corosync stack of 2 machines.

I was using it before with corosync1, but on Ubuntu 14.04 I've got corosync 2.3.3
OK - I said, and tried to use this version of software.

When i Prepare basic configuration with one ring - everything is ok. nodes are visible, and everything works super fine.

What i want to do is to enable encryption between nodes.
Documentation is not very helpful ;/ or maybe i'm just too stupid ;)

. How to enable cipher on corosync ?

In manual We can read:

```
          crypto_hash
          This specifies which HMAC authentication should be used to authenticate all messages. Valid values are none (no authentication), md5, sha1, sha256, sha384 and sha512.

          The default is sha1.

          crypto_cipher
          This specifies which cipher should be used to encrypt all messages.  Valid values are none (no encryption), aes256, aes192, aes128 and 3des.  Enabling crypto_cipher, requires also enabling of crypto_hash.

          The default is aes256.
```

Superb! So let's try to use it:
So in config, I've changed:

```
    crypto_cipher: none
    crypto_hash: none
```

to

```
    crypto_cipher: sha1
    crypto_hash: aes256
```

And What I've got?

```
Restarting corosync daemon corosync
error   [MAIN  ] Invalid cipher type
error   [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine exiting with status 8 at main.c:1158.
```

Whaaat? But It was said, that this is default. 
I can successfully use option secauth, but it is deprecated.

Every setting available for crypto_cipher is not recognized by corosync. WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exchanged the values ​​of the options, you must use:

```
crypto_cipher: aes256
crypto_hash: sha1
```

instead of

```
crypto_cipher: sha1
crypto_hash: aes256
```

Comment: Sorry. My fault, but only here i made this mistake, It didn't change anything. Still the same problem.

Comment: OK. The problem has been solved. I've manually updated 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 and it works. No Idea what was wrong.